# joining two objects distorts the shapes

Tags: mesh

basically I have two questions. both related to same problem.

I have a speeker product modeled in blender it has 4 different parts. 
question 1: when I join the 4 parts shape get distorted like they have never been subdivided and allinged before join but infact they was alligened and subdivided.

question 2: If I select all the parts and give rotation for animation. shapes get deformed again while playing rotation. please clear the problem thanks community in advance. file is attached.

Comment: I don't see any file attached but it seems that you are joining objects with different modifiers unapplied which get modifiers from active object (if any) while their own ones get removed. I can't tell about second question since it's too few details and probably you should ask it as a new question with explanation, screenshot and file

Comment: I have checked it again you sort out the right problem. thanks a lot man. modifiers was not applied after applying modifiers problem solved.